# Htaccess file not responding - Internal Server Error 500

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, internal-server-error

I am having trouble with .htaccess file, essentially I am just trying to rewrite the urls to be a bit more user friendly. So what I have for a url currently is something like this:

http://diverseevolution.com/index.php?url=about

What I want is something like this:

http://diverseevolution.com/about/

Finally I have written my own .htaccess file that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now I have tested this in other directories of my server and it works fine but under an actual domain and not just a sub directory it gives me a `Internal Server Error 500`

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does your apache error log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ([^/]+)/?   [NC]
RewriteRule .*  index.php?url=%1     [L,QSA]
```

It will map silently:

`http://diverseevolution.com/anything/`

To:

`http://diverseevolution.com/index.php?url=anything`

Comment: Thanks so much!!!! I actually only need to add the rewrite base to the file and it did everything else for me.

`pre``RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^((about)([^?]*)) index.php?url=about [L,NC]
```